# nmon installations in unix

Tags: unix, loadrunner

**Hi ,
I am trying to install nmon in Unix box.
nmon : nmon_x86_64_rhel6
Linux box is a 64 bit one too 
steps i did for installation:**

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/nmon/files/nmon_x86_64_rhel6
chmod +x nmon_x86_64_rhel6
ln -s nmon_x86_64_rhel6 nmon
export NMON=cmt
```

but when i invoke nmon
i am getting an error message saying 
****nmon: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory****

Answer (score 0):

Got the answere 
https://gist.github.com/sunggun-yu/4416430
Follow the steps and now the nmon is running fine